# Observable flatMap transformation error handling with passing the error-causing value

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Scenario:
Service needs to load a member-info. To do so, it needs 1) load member's id, and 2) load detailed info. Step 1 is mandatory (if it fails, the whole process should return an error), step 2 is optional (if it fails, a record with the id only is returned).

Environment: Angular 6, Typescript

Code:

```
public getMemberId() : Observable<string> { .. doing some http request ...}
public getMemberInfo(memberId : int) : Observable<Member> { 
  ... some code ... 
  return new Member(loaded_id, loaded_name);
}

// expected final usage:
loadUser().subscribe(
  res => ... at least member-id was loaded
  err => ... member-id was not loaded
)

// the not-working implementation:
public loadUser() : Observable<Member> {
  this.getMemberId().pipe(
    flatMap(id => getMemberInfo(id)),
    catchError(err => 
      new Member(id, "John Doe")) // how to get 'id' here??
}
```

I guess the "flatMap" is the right transformation for me as I am trying to convert the member-id into the full member-info. However, I don't know how to get in the `id` from the successfully finished `getMemberId()` function and pass it as a parameter in the `catchError` block when `getMemberInfo()` fails. The `catchError` has only an error object as a parameter, however I need to access the result of the upper Observable somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `catchError` in inner observable like this:

```
this.getMemberId()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(id => {
              return this.getMemberInfo(id)
                        .pipe(
                          catchError(error => {
                            return new Member(id, "John Doe")) // how to get 'id' here??
                          });
              })
          );
```

Use of `catchError` in inner observable will make id available while you are returning `Member` instance.

Comment: Eh, it's obvious. Thank you very much!